# Not Redirecting if User not Logged in but Have a redirect set up for when user not logged In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I do not understand why it is loading the page instead of directly redirecting. It used to work I don't know what it could be.

This is my **application.erb layout template**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pandora</title>
  <!-- Include needed.css files for use -->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'utilities/bootstrap.min'%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'utilities/font-awesome.min' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'elements/navbar' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'helpers' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'home' %>
  <!-- Include all existing js files for use -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <!-- Prelang: Analytics / Google Analytics -->
    <%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? or Rails.env.development? %>
</head>
<body>

<% require_user_signed_in %>

<!-- Render the navbar -->
<%= render partial: "elements/navbar" %>
<!-- Render the sidebar -->
<%= render partial: "elements/sidebar" %>
  <!-- Moves main content to the side to leave place for sidebar -->
  <div class=""></div>
  <!-- MAIN CONTENT Start -->
      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 main-chart">
            <!-- Renderes the popup notifications -->
            <% if flash[:notice] %>
              <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
            <% end %> <br>
              <!-- Renders everything in the page file -->
              <div class="main-move-up">
                <%= yield %>
              </div>
          </div><!-- /col-lg-9 END SECTION MIDDLE -->

          <div class="col-lg-3 ds">
            <%= render partial: "elements/notificationbar" %>
          </div><!--/col-lg-3 ds -->
        </section>
      </section>
      <!--main content end-->
      </section>

<!-- Renders the footer -->
<%= render partial: "elements/footer" %>


<!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<%= javascript_include_tag('dropdowns.js') %>

</body>
</html>
```

And I have this in my **application controller**:

```
def require_user_signed_in
    unless user_signed_in?

      # If the user came from a page, we can send them back.  Otherwise, send
      # them to the root path.
      # if request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
      #   fallback_redirect = :back
      if defined?(root_path)
        fallback_redirect = root_path
      else
        fallback_redirect = "/"
      end

      redirect_to fallback_redirect, flash: {error: "You must be signed in to view this page."}
    end
  end
```

**My problem:** I am getting the error `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` from `<%@companies=Company.where(:user_id => current_user.id)%>` (located in home.erb); this is normal since current_user doesn't exists when loading the page and not logged in. However what is not normal is that it is loading `<%= yield %>` which loads `home.erb`. It should load the method `<% require_user_signed_in %>` (located at the top of the template) first shoudn't it? And therfore redirect before it loads the rest of the page.

*Please let me know if you would like me to post more of my files from the project.*

Comment: You should not be calling `require_user_signed_in` from the view but from your controller. Views are only view, there are not supposed to execute any logical statement (or as little as possible), you should create two controller action and redirect the second one to the first one if the client isn' t connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [Controller Filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). From the RoR Guides:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :require_login
     
    private
     
    def require_login
        unless logged_in?
            flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
            redirect_to new_login_url 
        end
    end
end
```